# Which Trinity Universe Characters belong with each developer?

Tags: atelier, disgaea

In *Trinity Universe* a number of characters from games developed by Gust and Nippoin Ichi Software (NIS) are featured in it. some are obvious but i am wondering which characters belong to which developers and which may be original characters.

Bellow is a List of characters:

- Demon God (Dog) King Kanata
- Fox Spirit Tsubaki
- Suzaku
- Dark Hero Lucius
- Valkarie Rizelea
- Mizuki
- Violet
- Pamala
- Macaroon
- Miyu
- Recit
- Pirate Queen Etna
- Prinny (and in cutscenes, the Prinny Squad)
- Flonne (Fallen Angel)

NOTE: i have tagged [atelier](/questions/tagged/atelier) and [disgaea](/questions/tagged/disgaea) because i am assuming the characters would originate from these series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played the game, but according to [its English-language Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_Universe_%28video_game%29):

- Demon God Kanata
- Valkyrie Rizelea
- Fox Spirit Tsubaki
- The Dark Hero Lucius
- Treasure Hunter Recit
- Managraphic Artist Miyu
- Mizuki
- Suzaku
- Macaroon
- Shuten
- Ashura

are all original characters.

- Flonne
- Etna
- Prinny

are all Nippon Ichi characters from Disgaea: Hour of Darkness. (I can personally vouch for this one, since I've played Disgaea.)

- Pamela Ibis
- Violet Platane

are Gust characters from Atelier Viorate: Alchemist of Gramnad 2.