# Who is Macaroon?

Tags: atelier, hyperdimension-neptunia

In a side quest of the first Hyperdimension Neptunia game, you fight a boss called Macaroon. Here's an image of her (unsure if this is from the original or Re;Birth)

[image: Macaroon from Hyperdimension Neptunia]

In Trinity Universe, she appears as an Inn Keeper (before Pamula takes over) and as a shop keeper (before Violet takes over).

[image: Macaroon from Trinity Universe]

I've played though the Disgaea Games (with the exception to *Disgaea D2: a Brighter Darkness*, but it was released after Trinity Universe and Hyperdimension Neptunia) and I haven't seen her, so I assumed that she is a Gust character probably from the Atelier series, since both games feature Gust characters (Hyperdimension Neptunia has a character who represents Gust called Gust like how NISA has Nisa).

I thought she'd appear in the Atelier Iris series, but I'm currently on the third one and I have yet to meet her, but I know some of the Atelier Games were never localized and I'm assuming she's from the Atelier series (Gust also did *Ar Tonelico* and *Ar no Surge*).

So I am wondering, where does she appear? Or was she an original character only used in cross-over works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Torisuda's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14157/1587) to [another question of mine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14153/which-trinity-universe-characters-belong-with-each-developer) Macaroon seemed to be an original character in *Trinity Universe*.

Since Trinity Universe came out in 2009 and *Hyperdimension Neptunia* in 2010 it would seem that Macaroon is an original character used in cross-over works as such doesn't appear in any other previously released Gust Game.